# How do I find the width of an IPython cell?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, console

pandas dataframes are displayed nicely within the ipython cell. How does it do it?

The regular ways of getting the console width for Python do not seem to work for ipython cells.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to see what is the size you can use this script:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
js = """<script>
alert($( ".cell").width())
</script>"""
display(HTML(js))
```

If you want to use in code you can assign it to a variable and use it in next cell:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
js = """<script>
IPython.notebook.kernel.execute("cell_width="+($( ".cell").width()))
</script>"""
display(HTML(js))
```

In the next cell:

```
print(cell_width)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will make sure to test your suggestion and get back to you over the weekend :)

Comment: Tried this in vscode jupyter extension. Seems to not set/share `cell_width`. Exception: `NameError: name 'cell_width' is not defined`

Comment: Did you try updating your Jupyter notebook? Perhaps you are using previous versionos